# How can we use gRPC with Flatbuffers?

Tags: grpc, flatbuffers

I have been studying about Apache Thrift, ProtoBuf and Flatbuffers. I found the tutorial to use gRPC with protobuf at [link](http://www.grpc.io/docs/) but I am not finding any documentation to use gRPC with Flatbuffers. Can some one point me to the relevant documentation? I checked it on Google as well as on Stackoverflow. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The gRPC protocol is payload-agnostic, but the code generation is not. Since there isn't code generation already for FlatBuffers you will need to do some things manually.

The details vary by language, but the basic pieces are similar. As an example, in Go you would need to implement [Codec](https://godoc.org/google.golang.org/grpc#Codec) and prepare the descriptors necessary for [Invoke](https://godoc.org/google.golang.org/grpc#Invoke), [NewClientStream](https://godoc.org/google.golang.org/grpc#NewClientStream), and [RegisterService](https://godoc.org/google.golang.org/grpc#Server.RegisterService). In Java you would need to implement [Marshaller](http://www.grpc.io/grpc-java/javadoc/io/grpc/MethodDescriptor.Marshaller.html) and prepare the descriptors necessary for [newCall](http://www.grpc.io/grpc-java/javadoc/io/grpc/Channel.html#newCall-io.grpc.MethodDescriptor-io.grpc.CallOptions-) and [addService](http://www.grpc.io/grpc-java/javadoc/io/grpc/ServerBuilder.html#addService-io.grpc.ServerServiceDefinition-). If you have trouble, you may consider looking at the generated code for gRPC when used with Protobuf.

Comment: While it is in theory agnostic, in practice it is not set up well for things that are not protobuf. This could all be a lot easier. Please prod the gPRC maintainers to improve support for naked buffers, or directly support FlatBuffers.

Comment: It could be easier in general, or it could be easier for FlatBuffers in particular?

Comment: For FlatBuffers or any other serialization system that is not protobuf.

Comment: The IDL and codegen do need to vary reasonably with different serializers. Improving support for particular serializers is easier than arbitrary serializers. I do believe we are open to concrete suggestions for improvements that could be made.

Comment: Yeah, any suggestions to make it a lot easier are very welcome!

Answer (score 16):

Since this question was first asked, progress has been made in a) making GRPC codegen independent of protobuf (see https://github.com/grpc/grpc/pull/6130) and then to integrate that codegenerator in the flatbuffers compiler `flatc`: https://github.com/google/flatbuffers/commit/48f37f9e0a04f2b60046dda7fef20a8b0ebc1a70

This is a a very basic first implementation, feedback welcome.

Comment: This is pretty exciting!

Comment: @Aardappel I think there is some issue with `--grpc` can you please check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64063320/flatbuffers-when-grpc-is-used-error-no-template-named-streamedunaryhandler

Answer (score 4):

Since **2017-08-17** gRPC has out-of-the-box support for flatbuffers as mentioned in their blog https://grpc.io/blog/grpc-flatbuffers/#use-flatbuffers-as-an-idl

> The recent release of Flatbuffers **version 1.7** introduced truly zero-copy support for gRPC out of the box.

Example command from the linked article

```sh
flatc --cpp --grpc example.fbs
```

Comment: I would say not totally true, is not supported since some versions ago. See https://github.com/google/flatbuffers/issues/5836

Comment: I agree, after this answer I realised it still seems rough