# FlatBuffers - When --grpc is used error No template named 'StreamedUnaryHandler' in namespace 'grpc::internal'

Tags: c++, cmake, grpc, flatbuffers

I am using FlatBuffers and here is my schema:

```
namespace Vibranium;

table AccountRole_Packet {
    id:int;
    name:string;
}
table AccountRole_Packet_Response {
    id:int;
    name:string;
}
root_type AccountRole_Packet;

rpc_service AccountRole_Service {
    GetAccountRole(AccountRole_Packet):AccountRole_Packet_Response;
}
```

I do the following command:

```
flatc --grpc -c ./AccountRole_Packet.fbs
```

Which generates those files:

`AccountRole_Packet.grpc.fb.cc`:

```
// Generated by the gRPC C++ plugin.
// If you make any local change, they will be lost.
// source: AccountRole_Packet

#include "AccountRole_Packet_generated.h"
#include "AccountRole_Packet.grpc.fb.h"

#include <grpc++/impl/codegen/async_stream.h>
#include <grpc++/impl/codegen/async_unary_call.h>
#include <grpc++/impl/codegen/channel_interface.h>
#include <grpc++/impl/codegen/client_unary_call.h>
#include <grpc++/impl/codegen/method_handler_impl.h>
#include <grpc++/impl/codegen/rpc_service_method.h>
#include <grpc++/impl/codegen/service_type.h>
#include <grpc++/impl/codegen/sync_stream.h>
namespace Vibranium {

static const char* AccountRole_Service_method_names[] = {
  "/Vibranium.AccountRole_Service/GetAccountRole",
};

std::unique_ptr< AccountRole_Service::Stub> AccountRole_Service::NewStub(const std::shared_ptr< ::grpc::ChannelInterface>& channel, const ::grpc::StubOptions& options) {
  std::unique_ptr< AccountRole_Service::Stub> stub(new AccountRole_Service::Stub(channel));
  return stub;
}

AccountRole_Service::Stub::Stub(const std::shared_ptr< ::grpc::ChannelInterface>& channel)
  : channel_(channel)  , rpcmethod_GetAccountRole_(AccountRole_Service_method_names[0], ::grpc::internal::RpcMethod::NORMAL_RPC, channel)
  {}
  
::grpc::Status AccountRole_Service::Stub::GetAccountRole(::grpc::ClientContext* context, const flatbuffers::grpc::Message<AccountRole_Packet>& request, flatbuffers::grpc::Message<AccountRole_Packet_Response>* response) {
  return ::grpc::internal::BlockingUnaryCall(channel_.get(), rpcmethod_GetAccountRole_, context, request, response);
}

::grpc::ClientAsyncResponseReader< flatbuffers::grpc::Message<AccountRole_Packet_Response>>* AccountRole_Service::Stub::AsyncGetAccountRoleRaw(::grpc::ClientContext* context, const flatbuffers::grpc::Message<AccountRole_Packet>& request, ::grpc::CompletionQueue* cq) {
  return ::grpc::internal::ClientAsyncResponseReaderFactory< flatbuffers::grpc::Message<AccountRole_Packet_Response>>::Create(channel_.get(), cq, rpcmethod_GetAccountRole_, context, request, true);
}

::grpc::ClientAsyncResponseReader< flatbuffers::grpc::Message<AccountRole_Packet_Response>>* AccountRole_Service::Stub::PrepareAsyncGetAccountRoleRaw(::grpc::ClientContext* context, const flatbuffers::grpc::Message<AccountRole_Packet>& request, ::grpc::CompletionQueue* cq) {
  return ::grpc::internal::ClientAsyncResponseReaderFactory< flatbuffers::grpc::Message<AccountRole_Packet_Response>>::Create(channel_.get(), cq, rpcmethod_GetAccountRole_, context, request, false);
}

AccountRole_Service::Service::Service() {
  AddMethod(new ::grpc::internal::RpcServiceMethod(
      AccountRole_Service_method_names[0],
      ::grpc::internal::RpcMethod::NORMAL_RPC,
      new ::grpc::internal::RpcMethodHandler< AccountRole_Service::Service, flatbuffers::grpc::Message<AccountRole_Packet>, flatbuffers::grpc::Message<AccountRole_Packet_Response>>(
          std::mem_fn(&AccountRole_Service::Service::GetAccountRole), this)));
}

AccountRole_Service::Service::~Service() {
}

::grpc::Status AccountRole_Service::Service::GetAccountRole(::grpc::ServerContext* context, const flatbuffers::grpc::Message<AccountRole_Packet>* request, flatbuffers::grpc::Message<AccountRole_Packet_Response>* response) {
  (void) context;
  (void) request;
  (void) response;
  return ::grpc::Status(::grpc::StatusCode::UNIMPLEMENTED, "");
}


}  // namespace Vibranium
```

`AccountRole_Packet.grpc.fb.h`:

```
// Generated by the gRPC C++ plugin.
// If you make any local change, they will be lost.
// source: AccountRole_Packet
#ifndef GRPC_AccountRole_5fPacket__INCLUDED
#define GRPC_AccountRole_5fPacket__INCLUDED

#include "AccountRole_Packet_generated.h"
#include "flatbuffers/grpc.h"

#include <grpc++/impl/codegen/async_stream.h>
#include <grpc++/impl/codegen/async_unary_call.h>
#include <grpc++/impl/codegen/method_handler_impl.h>
#include <grpc++/impl/codegen/proto_utils.h>
#include <grpc++/impl/codegen/rpc_method.h>
#include <grpc++/impl/codegen/service_type.h>
#include <grpc++/impl/codegen/status.h>
#include <grpc++/impl/codegen/stub_options.h>
#include <grpc++/impl/codegen/sync_stream.h>

namespace grpc {
class CompletionQueue;
class Channel;
class ServerCompletionQueue;
class ServerContext;
}  // namespace grpc

namespace Vibranium {

class AccountRole_Service final {
 public:
  static constexpr char const* service_full_name() {
    return "Vibranium.AccountRole_Service";
  }
  class StubInterface {
   public:
    virtual ~StubInterface() {}
    virtual ::grpc::Status GetAccountRole(::grpc::ClientContext* context, const flatbuffers::grpc::Message<AccountRole_Packet>& request, flatbuffers::grpc::Message<AccountRole_Packet_Response>* response) = 0;
    std::unique_ptr< ::grpc::ClientAsyncResponseReaderInterface< flatbuffers::grpc::Message<AccountRole_Packet_Response>>> AsyncGetAccountRole(::grpc::ClientContext* context, const flatbuffers::grpc::Message<AccountRole_Packet>& request, ::grpc::CompletionQueue* cq) {
      return std::unique_ptr< ::grpc::ClientAsyncResponseReaderInterface< flatbuffers::grpc::Message<AccountRole_Packet_Response>>>(AsyncGetAccountRoleRaw(context, request, cq));
    }
    std::unique_ptr< ::grpc::ClientAsyncResponseReaderInterface< flatbuffers::grpc::Message<AccountRole_Packet_Response>>> PrepareAsyncGetAccountRole(::grpc::ClientContext* context, const flatbuffers::grpc::Message<AccountRole_Packet>& request, ::grpc::CompletionQueue* cq) {
      return std::unique_ptr< ::grpc::ClientAsyncResponseReaderInterface< flatbuffers::grpc::Message<AccountRole_Packet_Response>>>(PrepareAsyncGetAccountRoleRaw(context, request, cq));
    }
  private:
    virtual ::grpc::ClientAsyncResponseReaderInterface< flatbuffers::grpc::Message<AccountRole_Packet_Response>>* AsyncGetAccountRoleRaw(::grpc::ClientContext* context, const flatbuffers::grpc::Message<AccountRole_Packet>& request, ::grpc::CompletionQueue* cq) = 0;
    virtual ::grpc::ClientAsyncResponseReaderInterface< flatbuffers::grpc::Message<AccountRole_Packet_Response>>* PrepareAsyncGetAccountRoleRaw(::grpc::ClientContext* context, const flatbuffers::grpc::Message<AccountRole_Packet>& request, ::grpc::CompletionQueue* cq) = 0;
  };
  class Stub final : public StubInterface {
   public:
    Stub(const std::shared_ptr< ::grpc::ChannelInterface>& channel);
    ::grpc::Status GetAccountRole(::grpc::ClientContext* context, const flatbuffers::grpc::Message<AccountRole_Packet>& request, flatbuffers::grpc::Message<AccountRole_Packet_Response>* response) override;
    std::unique_ptr< ::grpc::ClientAsyncResponseReader< flatbuffers::grpc::Message<AccountRole_Packet_Response>>> AsyncGetAccountRole(::grpc::ClientContext* context, const flatbuffers::grpc::Message<AccountRole_Packet>& request, ::grpc::CompletionQueue* cq) {
      return std::unique_ptr< ::grpc::ClientAsyncResponseReader< flatbuffers::grpc::Message<AccountRole_Packet_Response>>>(AsyncGetAccountRoleRaw(context, request, cq));
    }
    std::unique_ptr< ::grpc::ClientAsyncResponseReader< flatbuffers::grpc::Message<AccountRole_Packet_Response>>> PrepareAsyncGetAccountRole(::grpc::ClientContext* context, const flatbuffers::grpc::Message<AccountRole_Packet>& request, ::grpc::CompletionQueue* cq) {
      return std::unique_ptr< ::grpc::ClientAsyncResponseReader< flatbuffers::grpc::Message<AccountRole_Packet_Response>>>(PrepareAsyncGetAccountRoleRaw(context, request, cq));
    }

   private:
    std::shared_ptr< ::grpc::ChannelInterface> channel_;
    ::grpc::ClientAsyncResponseReader< flatbuffers::grpc::Message<AccountRole_Packet_Response>>* AsyncGetAccountRoleRaw(::grpc::ClientContext* context, const flatbuffers::grpc::Message<AccountRole_Packet>& request, ::grpc::CompletionQueue* cq) override;
    ::grpc::ClientAsyncResponseReader< flatbuffers::grpc::Message<AccountRole_Packet_Response>>* PrepareAsyncGetAccountRoleRaw(::grpc::ClientContext* context, const flatbuffers::grpc::Message<AccountRole_Packet>& request, ::grpc::CompletionQueue* cq) override;
    const ::grpc::internal::RpcMethod rpcmethod_GetAccountRole_;
  };
  static std::unique_ptr<Stub> NewStub(const std::shared_ptr< ::grpc::ChannelInterface>& channel, const ::grpc::StubOptions& options = ::grpc::StubOptions());

  class Service : public ::grpc::Service {
   public:
    Service();
    virtual ~Service();
    virtual ::grpc::Status GetAccountRole(::grpc::ServerContext* context, const flatbuffers::grpc::Message<AccountRole_Packet>* request, flatbuffers::grpc::Message<AccountRole_Packet_Response>* response);
  };
  template <class BaseClass>
  class WithAsyncMethod_GetAccountRole : public BaseClass {
   private:
    void BaseClassMustBeDerivedFromService(const Service *service) {}
   public:
    WithAsyncMethod_GetAccountRole() {
      ::grpc::Service::MarkMethodAsync(0);
    }
    ~WithAsyncMethod_GetAccountRole() override {
      BaseClassMustBeDerivedFromService(this);
    }
    // disable synchronous version of this method
    ::grpc::Status GetAccountRole(::grpc::ServerContext* context, const flatbuffers::grpc::Message<AccountRole_Packet>* request, flatbuffers::grpc::Message<AccountRole_Packet_Response>* response) final override {
      abort();
      return ::grpc::Status(::grpc::StatusCode::UNIMPLEMENTED, "");
    }
    void RequestGetAccountRole(::grpc::ServerContext* context, flatbuffers::grpc::Message<AccountRole_Packet>* request, ::grpc::ServerAsyncResponseWriter< flatbuffers::grpc::Message<AccountRole_Packet_Response>>* response, ::grpc::CompletionQueue* new_call_cq, ::grpc::ServerCompletionQueue* notification_cq, void *tag) {
      ::grpc::Service::RequestAsyncUnary(0, context, request, response, new_call_cq, notification_cq, tag);
    }
  };
  typedef   WithAsyncMethod_GetAccountRole<  Service   >   AsyncService;
  template <class BaseClass>
  class WithGenericMethod_GetAccountRole : public BaseClass {
   private:
    void BaseClassMustBeDerivedFromService(const Service *service) {}
   public:
    WithGenericMethod_GetAccountRole() {
      ::grpc::Service::MarkMethodGeneric(0);
    }
    ~WithGenericMethod_GetAccountRole() override {
      BaseClassMustBeDerivedFromService(this);
    }
    // disable synchronous version of this method
    ::grpc::Status GetAccountRole(::grpc::ServerContext* context, const flatbuffers::grpc::Message<AccountRole_Packet>* request, flatbuffers::grpc::Message<AccountRole_Packet_Response>* response) final override {
      abort();
      return ::grpc::Status(::grpc::StatusCode::UNIMPLEMENTED, "");
    }
  };
  template <class BaseClass>
  class WithStreamedUnaryMethod_GetAccountRole : public BaseClass {
   private:
    void BaseClassMustBeDerivedFromService(const Service *service) {}
   public:
    WithStreamedUnaryMethod_GetAccountRole() {
      ::grpc::Service::MarkMethodStreamed(0,
        new ::grpc::internal::StreamedUnaryHandler< flatbuffers::grpc::Message<AccountRole_Packet>, flatbuffers::grpc::Message<AccountRole_Packet_Response>>(std::bind(&WithStreamedUnaryMethod_GetAccountRole<BaseClass>::StreamedGetAccountRole, this, std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2)));
    }
    ~WithStreamedUnaryMethod_GetAccountRole() override {
      BaseClassMustBeDerivedFromService(this);
    }
    // disable regular version of this method
    ::grpc::Status GetAccountRole(::grpc::ServerContext* context, const flatbuffers::grpc::Message<AccountRole_Packet>* request, flatbuffers::grpc::Message<AccountRole_Packet_Response>* response) final override {
      abort();
      return ::grpc::Status(::grpc::StatusCode::UNIMPLEMENTED, "");
    }
    // replace default version of method with streamed unary
    virtual ::grpc::Status StreamedGetAccountRole(::grpc::ServerContext* context, ::grpc::ServerUnaryStreamer< flatbuffers::grpc::Message<AccountRole_Packet>,flatbuffers::grpc::Message<AccountRole_Packet_Response>>* server_unary_streamer) = 0;
  };
  typedef   WithStreamedUnaryMethod_GetAccountRole<  Service   >   StreamedUnaryService;
  typedef   Service   SplitStreamedService;
  typedef   WithStreamedUnaryMethod_GetAccountRole<  Service   >   StreamedService;
};

}  // namespace Vibranium


#endif  // GRPC_AccountRole_5fPacket__INCLUDED
```

`AccountRole_Packet_generated.h`:

```
// automatically generated by the FlatBuffers compiler, do not modify


#ifndef FLATBUFFERS_GENERATED_ACCOUNTROLEPACKET_VIBRANIUM_H_
#define FLATBUFFERS_GENERATED_ACCOUNTROLEPACKET_VIBRANIUM_H_

#include "flatbuffers/flatbuffers.h"

namespace Vibranium {

struct AccountRole_Packet;
struct AccountRole_PacketBuilder;

struct AccountRole_Packet_Response;
struct AccountRole_Packet_ResponseBuilder;

struct AccountRole_Packet FLATBUFFERS_FINAL_CLASS : private flatbuffers::Table {
  typedef AccountRole_PacketBuilder Builder;
  enum FlatBuffersVTableOffset FLATBUFFERS_VTABLE_UNDERLYING_TYPE {
    VT_ID = 4,
    VT_NAME = 6
  };
  int32_t id() const {
    return GetField<int32_t>(VT_ID, 0);
  }
  const flatbuffers::String *name() const {
    return GetPointer<const flatbuffers::String *>(VT_NAME);
  }
  bool Verify(flatbuffers::Verifier &verifier) const {
    return VerifyTableStart(verifier) &&
           VerifyField<int32_t>(verifier, VT_ID) &&
           VerifyOffset(verifier, VT_NAME) &&
           verifier.VerifyString(name()) &&
           verifier.EndTable();
  }
};

struct AccountRole_PacketBuilder {
  typedef AccountRole_Packet Table;
  flatbuffers::FlatBufferBuilder &fbb_;
  flatbuffers::uoffset_t start_;
  void add_id(int32_t id) {
    fbb_.AddElement<int32_t>(AccountRole_Packet::VT_ID, id, 0);
  }
  void add_name(flatbuffers::Offset<flatbuffers::String> name) {
    fbb_.AddOffset(AccountRole_Packet::VT_NAME, name);
  }
  explicit AccountRole_PacketBuilder(flatbuffers::FlatBufferBuilder &_fbb)
        : fbb_(_fbb) {
    start_ = fbb_.StartTable();
  }
  flatbuffers::Offset<AccountRole_Packet> Finish() {
    const auto end = fbb_.EndTable(start_);
    auto o = flatbuffers::Offset<AccountRole_Packet>(end);
    return o;
  }
};

inline flatbuffers::Offset<AccountRole_Packet> CreateAccountRole_Packet(
    flatbuffers::FlatBufferBuilder &_fbb,
    int32_t id = 0,
    flatbuffers::Offset<flatbuffers::String> name = 0) {
  AccountRole_PacketBuilder builder_(_fbb);
  builder_.add_name(name);
  builder_.add_id(id);
  return builder_.Finish();
}

inline flatbuffers::Offset<AccountRole_Packet> CreateAccountRole_PacketDirect(
    flatbuffers::FlatBufferBuilder &_fbb,
    int32_t id = 0,
    const char *name = nullptr) {
  auto name__ = name ? _fbb.CreateString(name) : 0;
  return Vibranium::CreateAccountRole_Packet(
      _fbb,
      id,
      name__);
}

struct AccountRole_Packet_Response FLATBUFFERS_FINAL_CLASS : private flatbuffers::Table {
  typedef AccountRole_Packet_ResponseBuilder Builder;
  enum FlatBuffersVTableOffset FLATBUFFERS_VTABLE_UNDERLYING_TYPE {
    VT_ID = 4,
    VT_NAME = 6
  };
  int32_t id() const {
    return GetField<int32_t>(VT_ID, 0);
  }
  const flatbuffers::String *name() const {
    return GetPointer<const flatbuffers::String *>(VT_NAME);
  }
  bool Verify(flatbuffers::Verifier &verifier) const {
    return VerifyTableStart(verifier) &&
           VerifyField<int32_t>(verifier, VT_ID) &&
           VerifyOffset(verifier, VT_NAME) &&
           verifier.VerifyString(name()) &&
           verifier.EndTable();
  }
};

struct AccountRole_Packet_ResponseBuilder {
  typedef AccountRole_Packet_Response Table;
  flatbuffers::FlatBufferBuilder &fbb_;
  flatbuffers::uoffset_t start_;
  void add_id(int32_t id) {
    fbb_.AddElement<int32_t>(AccountRole_Packet_Response::VT_ID, id, 0);
  }
  void add_name(flatbuffers::Offset<flatbuffers::String> name) {
    fbb_.AddOffset(AccountRole_Packet_Response::VT_NAME, name);
  }
  explicit AccountRole_Packet_ResponseBuilder(flatbuffers::FlatBufferBuilder &_fbb)
        : fbb_(_fbb) {
    start_ = fbb_.StartTable();
  }
  flatbuffers::Offset<AccountRole_Packet_Response> Finish() {
    const auto end = fbb_.EndTable(start_);
    auto o = flatbuffers::Offset<AccountRole_Packet_Response>(end);
    return o;
  }
};

inline flatbuffers::Offset<AccountRole_Packet_Response> CreateAccountRole_Packet_Response(
    flatbuffers::FlatBufferBuilder &_fbb,
    int32_t id = 0,
    flatbuffers::Offset<flatbuffers::String> name = 0) {
  AccountRole_Packet_ResponseBuilder builder_(_fbb);
  builder_.add_name(name);
  builder_.add_id(id);
  return builder_.Finish();
}

inline flatbuffers::Offset<AccountRole_Packet_Response> CreateAccountRole_Packet_ResponseDirect(
    flatbuffers::FlatBufferBuilder &_fbb,
    int32_t id = 0,
    const char *name = nullptr) {
  auto name__ = name ? _fbb.CreateString(name) : 0;
  return Vibranium::CreateAccountRole_Packet_Response(
      _fbb,
      id,
      name__);
}

inline const Vibranium::AccountRole_Packet *GetAccountRole_Packet(const void *buf) {
  return flatbuffers::GetRoot<Vibranium::AccountRole_Packet>(buf);
}

inline const Vibranium::AccountRole_Packet *GetSizePrefixedAccountRole_Packet(const void *buf) {
  return flatbuffers::GetSizePrefixedRoot<Vibranium::AccountRole_Packet>(buf);
}

inline bool VerifyAccountRole_PacketBuffer(
    flatbuffers::Verifier &verifier) {
  return verifier.VerifyBuffer<Vibranium::AccountRole_Packet>(nullptr);
}

inline bool VerifySizePrefixedAccountRole_PacketBuffer(
    flatbuffers::Verifier &verifier) {
  return verifier.VerifySizePrefixedBuffer<Vibranium::AccountRole_Packet>(nullptr);
}

inline void FinishAccountRole_PacketBuffer(
    flatbuffers::FlatBufferBuilder &fbb,
    flatbuffers::Offset<Vibranium::AccountRole_Packet> root) {
  fbb.Finish(root);
}

inline void FinishSizePrefixedAccountRole_PacketBuffer(
    flatbuffers::FlatBufferBuilder &fbb,
    flatbuffers::Offset<Vibranium::AccountRole_Packet> root) {
  fbb.FinishSizePrefixed(root);
}

}  // namespace Vibranium

#endif  // FLATBUFFERS_GENERATED_ACCOUNTROLEPACKET_VIBRANIUM_H_
```

So far so good. However when I try to build I get the following error:

```
[ 10%] Building CXX object Source/Common/CMakeFiles/Common.dir/Server/Packets/AccountRole_Packet.grpc.fb.cc.o
In file included from /home/armegon/Vibranium-Core/Source/Common/Server/Packets/AccountRole_Packet.grpc.fb.cc:6:
/home/armegon/Vibranium-Core/Source/Common/Server/Packets/AccountRole_Packet.grpc.fb.h: In member function ‘void Vibranium::AccountRole_Service::WithAsyncMethod_GetAccountRole<BaseClass>::RequestGetAccountRole(grpc::ServerContext*, flatbuffers::grpc::Message<Vibranium::AccountRole_Packet>*, grpc::ServerAsyncResponseWriter<flatbuffers::grpc::Message<Vibranium::AccountRole_Packet_Response> >*, grpc::CompletionQueue*, grpc::ServerCompletionQueue*, void*)’:
/home/armegon/Vibranium-Core/Source/Common/Server/Packets/AccountRole_Packet.grpc.fb.h:90:106: error: no matching function for call to ‘grpc::Service::RequestAsyncUnary(int, grpc::ServerContext*&, flatbuffers::grpc::Message<Vibranium::AccountRole_Packet>*&, grpc::ServerAsyncResponseWriter<flatbuffers::grpc::Message<Vibranium::AccountRole_Packet_Response> >*&, grpc::CompletionQueue*&, grpc::ServerCompletionQueue*&, void*&)’
   90 |       ::grpc::Service::RequestAsyncUnary(0, context, request, response, new_call_cq, notification_cq, tag);
      |                                                                                                          ^
In file included from /usr/local/include/grpcpp/impl/codegen/async_stream_impl.h:25,
                 from /usr/local/include/grpcpp/impl/codegen/async_stream.h:22,
                 from /usr/local/include/grpc++/impl/codegen/async_stream.h:26,
                 from /home/armegon/Vibranium-Core/Source/Common/Server/Packets/AccountRole_Packet.grpc.fb.h:10,
                 from /home/armegon/Vibranium-Core/Source/Common/Server/Packets/AccountRole_Packet.grpc.fb.cc:6:
/usr/local/include/grpcpp/impl/codegen/service_type.h:130:8: note: candidate: ‘template<class Message> void grpc::Service::RequestAsyncUnary(int, grpc_impl::ServerContext*, Message*, grpc::internal::ServerAsyncStreamingInterface*, grpc::CompletionQueue*, grpc::ServerCompletionQueue*, void*)’
  130 |   void RequestAsyncUnary(int index, ::grpc_impl::ServerContext* context,
      |        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/local/include/grpcpp/impl/codegen/service_type.h:130:8: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from /home/armegon/Vibranium-Core/Source/Common/Server/Packets/AccountRole_Packet.grpc.fb.cc:6:
/home/armegon/Vibranium-Core/Source/Common/Server/Packets/AccountRole_Packet.grpc.fb.h:90:45: note:   cannot convert ‘context’ (type ‘grpc::ServerContext*’) to type ‘grpc_impl::ServerContext*’
   90 |       ::grpc::Service::RequestAsyncUnary(0, context, request, response, new_call_cq, notification_cq, tag);
      |                                             ^~~~~~~
/home/armegon/Vibranium-Core/Source/Common/Server/Packets/AccountRole_Packet.grpc.fb.h: In constructor ‘Vibranium::AccountRole_Service::WithStreamedUnaryMethod_GetAccountRole<BaseClass>::WithStreamedUnaryMethod_GetAccountRole()’:
/home/armegon/Vibranium-Core/Source/Common/Server/Packets/AccountRole_Packet.grpc.fb.h:118:31: error: ‘StreamedUnaryHandler’ in namespace ‘grpc::internal’ does not name a template type
  118 |         new ::grpc::internal::StreamedUnaryHandler< flatbuffers::grpc::Message<AccountRole_Packet>, flatbuffers::grpc::Message<AccountRole_Packet_Response>>(std::bind(&WithStreamedUnaryMethod_GetAccountRole<BaseClass>::StreamedGetAccountRole, this, std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2)));
      |                               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/armegon/Vibranium-Core/Source/Common/Server/Packets/AccountRole_Packet.grpc.fb.h:118:99: error: expected primary-expression before ‘,’ token
  118 |         new ::grpc::internal::StreamedUnaryHandler< flatbuffers::grpc::Message<AccountRole_Packet>, flatbuffers::grpc::Message<AccountRole_Packet_Response>>(std::bind(&WithStreamedUnaryMethod_GetAccountRole<BaseClass>::StreamedGetAccountRole, this, std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2)));
      |                                                                                                   ^
/home/armegon/Vibranium-Core/Source/Common/Server/Packets/AccountRole_Packet.grpc.fb.h:118:155: error: expected primary-expression before ‘>’ token
  118 |         new ::grpc::internal::StreamedUnaryHandler< flatbuffers::grpc::Message<AccountRole_Packet>, flatbuffers::grpc::Message<AccountRole_Packet_Response>>(std::bind(&WithStreamedUnaryMethod_GetAccountRole<BaseClass>::StreamedGetAccountRole, this, std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2)));
      |                                                                                                                                                           ^~
/home/armegon/Vibranium-Core/Source/Common/Server/Packets/AccountRole_Packet.grpc.fb.cc: In constructor ‘Vibranium::AccountRole_Service::Service::Service()’:
/home/armegon/Vibranium-Core/Source/Common/Server/Packets/AccountRole_Packet.grpc.fb.cc:47:29: error: ‘RpcMethodHandler’ in namespace ‘grpc::internal’ does not name a template type; did you mean ‘MethodHandler’?
   47 |       new ::grpc::internal::RpcMethodHandler< AccountRole_Service::Service, flatbuffers::grpc::Message<AccountRole_Packet>, flatbuffers::grpc::Message<AccountRole_Packet_Response>>(
      |                             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                             MethodHandler
/home/armegon/Vibranium-Core/Source/Common/Server/Packets/AccountRole_Packet.grpc.fb.cc:47:75: error: expected primary-expression before ‘,’ token
   47 |       new ::grpc::internal::RpcMethodHandler< AccountRole_Service::Service, flatbuffers::grpc::Message<AccountRole_Packet>, flatbuffers::grpc::Message<AccountRole_Packet_Response>>(
      |                                                                           ^
/home/armegon/Vibranium-Core/Source/Common/Server/Packets/AccountRole_Packet.grpc.fb.cc:47:123: error: expected primary-expression before ‘,’ token
   47 |       new ::grpc::internal::RpcMethodHandler< AccountRole_Service::Service, flatbuffers::grpc::Message<AccountRole_Packet>, flatbuffers::grpc::Message<AccountRole_Packet_Response>>(
      |                                                                                                                           ^
/home/armegon/Vibranium-Core/Source/Common/Server/Packets/AccountRole_Packet.grpc.fb.cc:47:179: error: expected primary-expression before ‘>’ token
   47 |       new ::grpc::internal::RpcMethodHandler< AccountRole_Service::Service, flatbuffers::grpc::Message<AccountRole_Packet>, flatbuffers::grpc::Message<AccountRole_Packet_Response>>(
      |                                                                                                                                                                                   ^~
make[3]: *** [Source/Common/CMakeFiles/Common.dir/build.make:226: Source/Common/CMakeFiles/Common.dir/Server/Packets/AccountRole_Packet.grpc.fb.cc.o] Error 1
make[3]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:256: Source/Common/CMakeFiles/Common.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:317: Source/Core/AuthServer/CMakeFiles/AuthServer.dir/rule] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:210: AuthServer] Error 2
```

Here is my main `CMakeLists.txt` file: [Link Here](https://pastebin.com/EeNNsBvG)

And here is `CMakeLists.txt` of `Common` library where I use FlatBuffers: [Link Here](https://pastebin.com/MT7mxiqz)

On `AccountRole_Packet.grpc.fb.h:118` I have this `new ::grpc::internal::StreamedUnaryHandler` when I hover over `new ::grpc::internal::` I see the IDE giving me the following error:

```
No template named 'StreamedUnaryHandler' in namespace 'grpc::internal'; did you mean 'grpc_impl::internal::StreamedUnaryHandler'?
```

Why am I receiving this error ? How can I fix it?

Comment: https://github.com/google/flatbuffers/issues/5836

Comment: @Aardappel can I use latest Flatbuffers with grpc 1.16.0 ?